# Insert plain text between two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some HTML, like this:

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="foo1">foo1</div>
    <div id="foo2">foo2</div>
    <div id="foo3">foo3</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way using jQuery to insert the plain text `Bar` directly in between `#foo2` and `#foo3`, so the resultant HTML would be like this:

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="foo1">foo1</div>
    <div id="foo2">foo2</div>
    Bar
    <div id="foo3">foo3</div>
</div>
```

I am able to put the text in with a `<span>` tag using `$("<span/>").text("Bar").insertAfter("#foo2")`, but is there a way to just put the plain text there, without a `<span>` around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.after`:

```js
$('#foo2').after('bar');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="foo1">foo1</div>
    <div id="foo2">foo2</div>
    <div id="foo3">foo3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.createTextNode("bar")`:

```js
$("#foo2").after(document.createTextNode("bar"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="foo1">foo1</div>
    <div id="foo2">foo2</div>
    <div id="foo3">foo3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case you need an alternative with plain JavaScript, you can use [`insertAdjacentText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentText)

```js
document.getElementById('foo2').insertAdjacentText('afterend', 'bar');
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="foo1">foo1</div>
  <div id="foo2">foo2</div>
  <div id="foo3">foo3</div>
</div>
```

In case you are interested, the first argument provides other alternatives:

> element.insertAdjacentText(**position**, **element**);
>
> **position**
>
> *A `DOMString` representing the position relative to the element; must be one of the following strings:*
>
> - *`'beforebegin'`: Before the element itself.*
> - *`'afterbegin'`: Just inside the element, before its first child.*
> - *`'beforeend'`: Just inside the element, after its last child.*
> - *`'afterend'`: After the element itself.*
>
> **element**
>
> *A `DOMString` representing the text to be inserted into the tree.*